Could not find relevant COT data based on the current symbol and the source search mode `Auto` at #global():21
var string CFTC_Code_fixed = cot.convertRootToCOTCode("Auto")

Problem:

Could not find relevant COT data based on the current symbol and the
source search mode Auto at #global():21

I am stuck so I have no idea at all

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
